How to install Canon Utility (running under Wine) in Ubuntu 24.04?
I installed Wine.
I downloaded and extracted the canon utility-installer.
When I try to install it, using wine sudo wine euw3.18.40.9-installer.exe, I get an error
0074:err:ole:start_rpcss Failed to start RpcSs service
(actually the error message appears twice)
Nevertheless, some file are extracted.
Then a new error appears (in an pop up window)
Installation Program of EOS Utility Installer requires administrator privileges.
Actually, I don't know what happens when I push OK. I can't find the installed file an de 'virtual' C-drive... So I'm helples...
Thanks
